# Soap Request FaultException.Detail is always empty

Tags: c#, .net, soap, wsdl, faultexception

I am using a third party service & hence has no access to change anything from service side. I WSDL which I added as connect service.

The problem is that I have enabled the raw request & I can see error details in trace or debug log. But When I try to fetch details using following code it always return empty Detail Object.

```
try {
   // my code to call service
}
catch (System.ServiceModel.FaultException<Error[]> errors) {
    var err = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errors.Detail)
    Console.WriteLine(err);
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output received? What's in `Detail`, `{}`?

Comment: I'd also be curious to what the WSDL reference file looks like for the `XmlTypeAttribute` for the supposed `TypeName = "ErrorDetail"`. It sounds like a problem deserializing from the type returned from your vendor to the type specified in the WSDL.

Comment: If you `catch (Exception ex)` what kind of exception do you see? Soap faults were really badly implemented, it never threw exception the way we wanted so we had to return a result with error as result.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669955/faultexception-detail-coming-back-empty

Answer (score 0):

Edit: looks to be a duplicate of
[FaultException.Detail coming back empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669955/faultexception-detail-coming-back-empty)

> The problem was the visual studio didn't quite map out the ErrorDetail objects right. The ErrorDetail node is called "ErrorDetail", but the type generated for it is "ErrorDetailType." I edited the reference.cs class generated for each service I was using and added a TypeName:

Comment: Can you please explain in detail. I have a Reference.cs in which I can see a class called Error. I can't find anything called "ErrorDetailType" or not even "ErrorDetail". I did Find for "ErrorDetailType" and "ErrorDetail" in the complete file but found no results.